# Fastify + Boom not returning anything other than 500

Tags: node.js, fastify

Here is a part of my code I am trying

```
const boom = require('boom')
exports.checkOtp = async (req, reply) => {
    try {
        return boom.badRequest('no active otp')
    } catch (err) {
        throw boom.boomify(err)
    }
}
```

I am getting

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "no active otp"
}
```

`boom.badRequest` should fire a `400` right?

Comment: Maybe the error has not been fire at `boom.badRequest('no active otp')`, you could add a log in `catch` block to make sure that your code does not throw any unexpected error. Or just find `no active otp` string in whole the project.

Comment: There is no `no active otp` anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Boom is a module built and designed by hapi for hapi.

You should use the (unofficial) [`fastify-boom`](https://github.com/jeromemacias/fastify-boom) plugin or add your status code:

```
const boom = require('boom')
exports.checkOtp = async (req, reply) => {
    try {
        reply.code(400)
        return boom.badRequest('no active otp')
    } catch (err) {
        reply.code(500)
        throw boom.boomify(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just using throw error? and creating new error just by throw it

```
const err = new Error();
err.statusCode = 400;
err.message = 'message';
throw err;
```